# Focus in touch mode

Tags: android, google-tv

I have the ListView with categories and gridview with items for selected category.

**I need this: when I choose a category by clicking - set focus on first item in gridview.**
But now it works when I choose a category by keyboard...

Some code:

```
    gridView.requestFocus();
    gridView.setSelection(0);
```

Some Logs:

```
     gridView.isInTouchMode: true
     gridView.isFocusableInTouchMode: true
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code :

```
gridView.setFocusable(true); 
gridView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

And also set this attribute in your `GriView`

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: Problem in touch mode only??

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue with this code:

```
    gridView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    gridView.setSelection(0);
```